# Is there a way to do conditional subtraction in between pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do a conditional subtraction between two columns in pandas. But i am not sure how to do it.

I have a data frame which would look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'CREATED_DT_DTTM_EPOCH': [
        1483302261,
        1483305054,
        1483357692,
        1483385453,
        1483391215
    ],
    'Audit_Epoch': [0, 1483383670, 0, 0, 0]
})
```

I want to get the difference between the Audit Epoch and Created DT

```
df['Difference'] = df['Audit_Epoch'] - df['CREATED_DT_DTTM_EPOCH']
```

However I want it to return the same value of the created dt incase the value in audit epoch is 0. So i want to check for 0 in audit_epoch and if its 0 then return the created_dt_epoch value.
Hence it would be like this:

```
expected = pd.DataFrame({
    'CREATED_DT_DTTM_EPOCH': [
        1483302261,
        1483305054,
        1483357692,
        1483385453,
        1483391215
    ],
    'Audit_Epoch': [0,1483383670,0,0,0],
    'Difference': [
        1483302261,
        78616,
        1483357692,
        1483385453,
        1483391215
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

if `df['CREATED_DT_DTTM_EPOCH']` is always less than `df['Audit_Epoch']` you can do

```
df['Difference'] = (df['Audit_Epoch'] - df['CREATED_DT_DTTM_EPOCH']).abs()
```

or, in general, you can do

```
df['Difference'] = df['CREATED_DT_DTTM_EPOCH']
df.loc[df['Audit_Epoch'].ne(0), 'Difference'] = df['Audit_Epoch'] - df['CREATED_DT_DTTM_EPOCH']
```

Comment: safe way `np.where(df.Audit_Epoch.eq(0),df.CREATED_DT_DTTM_EPOCH,df.Audit_Epoch-df.CREATED_DT_DTTM_EPOCH)
`